Clustering model selection
I have a dataframe with the below columns and I want to find a clustering model that would reveil port clusters to take then some strategic actions. Given that I have mainly categorical values and the only numerical are coordinates with which clustering algorithm would be the best way to go?
K-Prototypes , DBSCAN?
And should I calculate my own dissimilarity matrix with haversine distance for the coords and Gower distance for categorical values?
I am a bit confused on this. Thanks!
port_call_id             object
voyage_id                object
vessel_id                object
port_id                  object
creation_date            object
pre_post_event           object
port                     object
longitude               float64
latitude                float64
is_terminal_required       bool
is_berth_required          bool
state                    object
unlocode                 object
country                  object
continent                object
timezone_id              object
voyage_type              object
buyer_id                 object
vessel_type              object
vessel_size              object
in Red Sea               object
